# JPA how to group by a collection property

Tags: jpa, collections, group-by

Is there a way to group by a collection property? For example,

```
public class Merchandise {
   id,
   name

}

public class Attribute {
    id,
    name,
    value,

    @ManyToOne
    MerchandiseCost merchandiseCost;
}

public class MerchandiseCost {
    Merchandise merchandise,
    List<Attribute> attributes,
    BigDecimal cost,
}
```

Search MerchandiseCost group by merchandise and attributes.

```
select merchandise, attributes, sum(cost) from MerchandiseCost group by merchandise, attributes.
```

Will this be going to work?

EDIT:
If not, how to build a query to get results as following using CriteriaQuery API:

```
Merchandise         Attributes         SUM(COST)
-----------------------------------------------------------
Cloth          size:L, color:RED       10000
Cloth          size:M, color:WHITE     20000
Computer       Memory:4G               80000
Computer       Memory:16G              90000
```

Comment: The SQL query itself looks OK.  Have you tried anything yet?

Comment: Why not explicitly add a JOIN to _attributes_ so then you can access its fields? That is necessary to be able to refer to a field of Attribute. Also you cannot use a multi-valued field in the SELECT clause.

Comment: Added the example of query results. If JOIN the collection member entity, how to achieve the query results as shown? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can not group by a collection and cannot select multi-valued field in the Select clause.

Merchandise.class

```
@Data
@Embeddable
@NoArgsConstructor
@EqualsAndHashCode
public class Merchandise {
    private String name;
}
```

Attribute.class

```
@Data
@Embeddable
@EqualsAndHashCode
public class Attribute {
private int id;
private String name;
private String value;

private MerchandiseCost merchandiseCost;

@ManyToOne
public MerchandiseCost getMerchandiseCost() {
    return merchandiseCost;
}
}
```

MerchandiseCost.class

```
@Data
@Entity
@EqualsAndHashCode
public class MerchandiseCost extends ABaseEntity {
private Merchandise merchandise;
private List<Attribute> attributes;

private BigDecimal cost;

@Embedded
public Merchandise getMerchandise() {
    return merchandise;
}

public void setMerchandise(Merchandise merchandise) {
    this.merchandise = merchandise;
}

@ElementCollection
@CollectionTable(name = "MERCHANDISE_ATTRIBUTE", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "MERCHANDISE_ID"))
public List<Attribute> getAttributes() {
    return attributes;
}
}
```

MerchandiseResult.class

```
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@EqualsAndHashCode
public class MerchandiseResult {
private Merchandise merchandise;
private Attribute attribute;
private BigDecimal cost;
}

MerchandiseDao.class

    @Stateless
    public class MerchandiseDao {
    @PersistenceContext(name = "tngo")
    private EntityManager entityManager;

    public void readCost(){
        Query query = entityManager.createQuery("select NEW tngo.cert.training.model.MerchandiseResult(mc.merchandise, att, sum(mc.cost)) from MerchandiseCost mc join mc.attributes att group by mc.merchandise, att");
        query.getResultList();
    }
    }
```